# NSURLConnection creating connectionTestFunction

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm currently using NSURLConnection to test if I can successfully connect to a server. Up until now, everything has worked flawlessly. The delegate methods get called, I can do what i want. But when I want to set a BOOL called connected in.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    self.connected = YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    self.connected = NO;
}
```

I always get NO.

I'm using my connection class in another class. I access my variable by doing this.

```
Connection *connection = [[Connection alloc] init];
[connection connectTo:@"localhost"];
connection.connected;<------ this is always NO.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connectTo method is being called asynchronously. Meaning, after calling connectTo, the execution will proceed immediately to the next line where you check for your connected property. It won't wait for the connection to receive a response.

Also, you may want to take a look at Apple's Reachability class, which is provided for exactly this sort of connection testing:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability